# Can anyone check if this correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning, spherical-coordinates

Convert to spherical coordinates and evaluate:$$\iiint_{E}z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-3/2}dV$$ where E is the region satisfying the following inequalities:$$x^2+y^2+z^2\le16,z\ge 2$$
This is what i have done so far.

$$E=(\rho,\theta,\phi):0\le\phi\le\pi/3, 0\le\theta\le2\pi, 2/cos\phi\le\rho\le4$$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \int_{2/cos\phi}^{4} \cos\phi\sin\phi \ d\rho d\phi d\theta\ = (\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta) (\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \rho \ cos\phi\sin\phi |_{\rho= 2/cos\phi}^{\rho=4} \ d\phi)$$

Can anyone check if this is correct please.

Comment: Your $E$ is off. For instance, given  $\phi$, then the radius is not between $2$ and $4$, it's between however far out you need to go to make the $z$-coordinate equal to $2$, and $4$. This _depends_ on $\phi$. That also means you cannot split the integral into three separate parts. Also, where did the integrand go? Lastly, there are some substitution details concerning the swap from $dx\,dy\,dz$ to $d\theta\,d\phi\,d\rho$.

Comment: @Arthur then the  radius is between $$2, and ,cos\phi?$$

Comment: @Arthur how did you get $2 cos\phi$?

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. It is $2/{\cos \phi}$. If we move $2/{\cos \phi}$ away from the origin, then the $z$ coordinate is $2$.

Comment: @Arthur now is my E alright?

Comment: Your $E$ looks good, but your integral is still messy. Where does $\cos\phi\sin\phi$ come from? When transforming from Cartesian to spherical, you follow $$\iiint f\,dx\,dy\,dz=\iiint f \rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$$(where you use whatever order of integration suits you). The $f$ itself also needs to be transformed to spherical.

Comment: @Arthur yeah but the $  \rho cos\phi (\rho^2)^{-3/2} (\rho^2) sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$ is only  $sin\phi cos\phi$